# flask_1 | WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: docker, google-chrome, ubuntu, driver, python-3.8

## Steps I followed build using docker-compose

I setup python robot framework with flask based application

### I created Dockerfile

#### DockerFile

FROM alpine:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ls -la /
RUN apk add --no-cache sqlite py3-pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENV FLASK_PORT 8181
ENV FLASK_APP demo_app
CMD ["sh", "run.sh"]
COPY testing/ui/config/ /app/tests/config/
COPY testing/ui/pages/ /app/tests/pages/
COPY testing/ui/steps/ /app/tests/steps/
COPY testing/ui/test_data/ /app/tests/test_data/
COPY testing/ui/tests/ /app/tests/tests/
COPY testing/ui/test_suites/ /app/tests/test_suites/
RUN ls -la /
WORKDIR /app/tests/test_suites/
CMD ["sh","run_ui_negative_tests.sh"]

## I created docker-compose file

version: '3'
services:
flask:
hostname: demoapp
image: demoapp:0.0.1
build:
context: .
dockerfile: ./Dockerfile

```
links:
  - chrome
tty: true
```

chrome:
image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-alpha-7-prerelease-20201009
volumes:
- /dev/shm:/dev/shm
depends_on:
- selenium-hub
environment:
- SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
- SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
- SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
ports:
- "5900:5900"

selenium-hub:
image: selenium/hub:4.0.0-alpha-7-prerelease-20201009
container_name: selenium-hub
ports:
- "4442:4442"

## Error I got

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
h

Comment: So, did you do what the error suggests you do? Did you try putting chromedriver somewhere in your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add path where your chrome driver application is stored.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'your_path\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: how to add in the docker machine

Comment: locally its working fine , when build using docker compose up getting an exception and its build libraries using requirements automatically